# Find function $f$ having it's gradient

Tags: derivatives, partial-derivative

I need to find function $f$ having it's gradient.
$$
\operatorname{grad} f = (x \cos y − 2)j + i \sin y
$$
I think $i$ and $j$ are some sort of vectors, but I'm not sure..
how to find function f?

I know, that a gradient is a vector of the fastest growth, but I don't see any vector right here.

Comment: i, j, and k are often used to denote the unit vectors in the x, y, and k directions respectively.  So if someone wrote 5i+2j+9k what they mean is the vector <5,2,9>.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Searching a proper $f(x,y)$ will lead us to have $$f_x=\sin y,~~~f_y=x\cos y-2$$ Let $f_x=\sin y$ then $f(x,y)=x\sin y+h(y)$ for some proper function $h(y)$. Now we have $f_y=x\cos y+h'(y)$, but $f_y=x\cos y-2$. So, $$h'(y)=2$$ and then $h(y)=2y$.

Comment: Ok, thank you :). What about i and j? do we skip them?

Comment: i is a unit vector in the x-direction and j a unit vector in the y-direction

Comment: ok, could you tell me how to write a normal gradient vector from this equation?

Comment: @TomDavies92: $\nabla f=f_x\textbf{i}+f_y\textbf{j}$

Comment: @Babak S. < Thank you, but I meant to write it using [] brackets - are you able to show me that? It'd help me a lot :).

Comment: @TomDavies92: Dear Tom, I really don't know the way you asked (using brackets) or I don't understand. Because $\nabla f$ is that normal vector and you have it in your hand.

Comment: I think I found out:
I mean:
$$
gradf = [siny, xcosy-2]
$$
am I right?

Comment: @TomDavies92: Yes! I see now what you asked. yes it is right.